# Converting colorspace in Imagemagick is not working

Tags: bitmap, imagemagick, grayscale, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert an sRGB bitmap file to greyscale using ImageMagick. I've tried using `convert -set colorspace Gray` and `convert colorspace Gray`, which according to the documentation should do it. However, when I try to check the output file using

```
identify -format "%[colorspace]" <outputfile>
```

it still tells me that it is in sRGB. I am aware that not all file formats support all colourspaces, and tried converting the bitmap to a png first, then changing the colorspace and converting it back. `identify` acknowledged that my png was in Gray colorspace, but this reverted back to sRGB when I reconverted to bitmap.

I have tried using the `-profile` option to change colourspace, but this does not seem to work. I'm not certain that bitmap files can accept profiles? I should also add that I have no way apart from using `identify` to tell whether any colourspace changes have been applied; the actual images are greyscale already, but I am trying to prep them for use with a program which will not accept colour bitmaps, only true greyscale.

Has anyone else had this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `BMP` format files?

Comment: I don't think`BMP` format supports grayscale in the true sense that there is only a single channel, so ImageMagick *fakes it* and produces three channels (RG&B) wherein all three channels are identical - as such, `identify` still perceives it as a 3-channel (and therefore `sRGB`) image. If you search for `grey` or `gray` on the Wikipedia page that describes BMP files you get nothing - it does not appear... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: If you have an image that does work with your program, maybe post a link to that and it may be possible to work out how to make ImageMagick produce something similar.

Comment: I do indeed mean BMP format files, sorry. And yes, I suspected the problem might be something like that. Unfortunately the software is not generally available - it was written for academic use and was sent from another institution for the use of the research group I work in. There is barely any documentation for it. All I know is that it definitely works with greyscale input only, that when giving it input it lists `bitmap (bmp)` as a supported data type, and then I get the error `24-colour bitmap format not supported` when I use my BMP files as-is.

Comment: If it is objecting to 24-bit truecolour images, you could try forcing a palettised image... `convert InputImage.xyz -colorspace gray -type palette result.bmp`

Comment: If you have an image that does work with your program, maybe post a link to that image and it may be possible to work out how to make ImageMagick produce something similar.