# Image Magick Not Converting Color Space

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to use ImageMagick to convert a png image to a bmp image and change its colorspace from BMP to Gray.

I'm using ImageMagick through the OSx Command line.

As far as I can tell this command should work, but it only changes the file type and not the colorspace.

```
convert fullpage.png -set colorspace Gray fullpage.bmp
```

Does anyone know what command I should be using?

Comment: Possibly BMP (BMP4) does not support colorspace gray in its header. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format. I do not see support for colorspace gray. Imagemagick knows it is grayscale from checking to see that all channels are the same, so it assigns it type=grayscale, but leaves the colorspace=sRGB. See also http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm

Comment: Okay, so if the header doesn't access grayscale, but the channels can be grayscale, how can I convert the channel of the original image?

THanks

Comment: I suspect you cannot get a single channel for BMP as grayscale. It will be 3 equal (RGB) channels. You could try `convert rose: -colorspace gray +dither -colors 256 -depth 8 -type palette rose.bmp`. But I suspect that may not make a difference.

Comment: Perhaps you issue is the BMP type and not the colorspace. Perhaps your software needs BMP3 or BMP2 rather than BMP (BMP4). So try `convert rose: -colorspace gray +dither -colors 256 -depth 8 -type palette BMP3:rose.bmp` Also try -type grayscale.

Comment: See https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=26268 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453498/converting-colorspace-in-imagemagick-is-not-working for a discussion of BMP to gray. It says that BMP does not support colorspace grayscale. You can, however, have a single channel palette type (vs 3-channel 24-bit total RGB) that is a grayscale palette. My commands above should do that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out BMP doesn't support a Gray colorspac, but because I also need a 4 bit color channel I managed to do this with ppmtobmp